# Vue 3 add multiple values to an array

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I'm trying to add **multiple values** the `checkedVessels` but it doesn't seem to work.

Here's what I tried

Vue template

```
<tr v-for="vessel in vessels.data" :key="vessel.id">
    <Input type="checkbox" v-model="checkedVessels" :value="vessel.id" />
</tr>
```

Vue Script

```
data () {
    return {
        term: '',
        importing: false,
        exporting: false,
        form: this.$inertia.form({
            file: null
        }),
        checkedVessels: []
    }
},
```

The docs mention what I could do something like this but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong

https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/forms.html#checkbox

I know I could implemented it doing something like

```html
<Input type="checkbox" @click="checkedVessels.push(vessel.id)" />
```

But the docs implementation looks cleaner to me

**Edit:**

I used `input` HTML element instead of my custom `Input` component and it seems to works fine.

Is there anything I can do to update my custom `Input` component to make it work just like the regular `input` HTML element?

Input.vue

```html
<template>
<input class="border-gray-300 focus:border-indigo-300 focus:ring focus:ring-indigo-200 focus:ring-opacity-50 rounded-md shadow-sm" :value="modelValue" @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)" ref="input">
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: ['modelValue'],

    emits: ['update:modelValue'],

    methods: {
        focus() {
            this.$refs.input.focus()
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I tried it out and It works fine, are you sure that `vessel.id` is passed correctly?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim yes when I use my custom Input it just adds the latest value as a string. `checkedVessels:"8"`

Comment: https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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

Comment: Bl8pmUV0LK+w6WdTLfOoNO4Xatep33MjNGoJkV/CnqQFISLEUibS8YnebLdraH4hIv0xQYl+yIpLmbeg4UznD9plWb19PYF/MFAFQ==

Comment: concatenate the two last comments and go to the link

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim this just adds the last checked string instead of pushing it to the `checkedVessels` array

Comment: Ah ok, I didn't notice that

Answer (score 0):

What about using a computed with getter and setter? This way you can still use v-model:

Input.vue

```html
<template>
  <input v-model="modelComp" ref="input" class="border-gray-300 focus:border-indigo-300 focus:ring focus:ring-indigo-200 focus:ring-opacity-50 rounded-md shadow-sm">
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['modelValue'],
  computed: {
    modelComp: {
      get: function() {
        return this.modelValue;
      },
      set: function(newValue) {
        this.$emit("update:modelValue", newValue);
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    focus() {
      this.$refs.input.focus()
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I made the complete example in Playground:

[Playground example](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

Please give it a try and let me know if you find this helpful.